# session_start() [function.session-start]

Tags: joomla, installation, joomla2.5

When I go to my local host, I receive this massage on top of the window.

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]:
 open(C:/Users/Tem/AppData/Local/Temp\sess_9f20c149aca0a77bee562d46784ea568, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in C:\AppServ\www\fhtrading\libraries\joomla\session\session.php on line 532
```

What is this exactly? and how to fix it?

I am a beginner so please assist me in this.

I am trying to install Joomla 2.5 version.

I already copied the files into the `appserv` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a server that you have ADMIN rights to? You're going to need to give `IIS` permissions  to the sessions folder OR go into the `php.ini` file and change the sessions folder to one that already has the permissions you need.

Comment: Yes, I do have the admin right to my machine. how do I give IIS permissions to the session folder. am using windows 7 pro.

Comment: Find the `C:\users\tem\appdata\local\temp` folder and under `Permissions` add **IIS_IUSR** with **Full Control**. If this doesn't work, try adding **Everyone**.

Comment: If the permissions did not fix it, check the `php.ini` file and change the sessions folder to `C:\Windows\Temp`.

Comment: so i should cut and paste the sessions folder from the joomla folder into the path you mentioned?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, it will just begin creating new sessions.

Comment: Sorry, you may have to hop onto the Joomla support forums with this one.

Comment: Sir, thank you so much for your time and efforts. I highly appreciate it :)